# How to encapsulate adding and removing related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using EF.Core I have a model where I have a group with items.

```
class Group
{
  public ICollection<Item> Items {get;}= new List<Item>();
}
class Item
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I want to ensure that names are unique when adding items to a group. How can I do that?

If I make group.Items private and add group.AddItem(Item item) I can't use .Include(x=> x.Items) on groups.

I know it can be done at db level.

Comment: You could probably use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`. Note that you'd have to specify an appropriate `IEqualityComparer` when creating it, that would compare `Item` objects by `Name` rather than by reference.

Comment: Be aware that `HashSet<T>` does implement `ICollection<T>`, as is required there, but it doesn't implement `IList<T>`, so you want be able to index it to get or set items like you would a `List<T>`. You get a `Count` property and you can enumerate it with a `foreach` loop, along with the methods like `Add` and `Remove`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the `Add` method of the `HashSet` class returns a `bool` to indicate whether the item was added or, if it was a duplicate, not added. If you call add via a reference of type `ICollection` then you're calling the explicit implementation the `ICollection.Add` method, which is declared `void`. I'm not sure which calls which but I suspect it's the bad way, so you'd probably have to cast as type `HashSet` to get the benefit.